# Blank included in blockRegexes

Tags: python, regex, validation, input

I am trying to make a math quiz: correct answer for the question is covered by allowRegexes and any other incorrect answer is covered by blockRegexes - any other answer but blanks.

Now, when I input a blank as an answer - a space for instance - it shows me "blank values are not allowed" and makes me re-enter my answer. But I want my code to give "incorrect" reply and skip to the next question, when input is a blank.
How do I do it? I tried to add an if statement or somehow add it to "blockRegexes" part, but I failed.

````
try:
    pyinputplus.inputStr(task, allowRegexes=['^%s$' % (num1 * num2)], blockRegexes = [('.*', 'Incorrect')],timeout = 5, limit =1)```

Thank you for any suggestions on how can I implement that into my code.
````

Comment: Should you try to separate the regex and put them into a container callable function ? Surely a single regex can validate input.

Comment: @sln I am afraid I do not understand what is "container callable function" - sorry I am just starting learning - could you explain it a bit?

Comment: Its just a callable Python function like `def isAllowedDissallowed( str_to_check):` that contains a single regex that checks the input string and returns true / false. The bigger point is all regexes can and should be combined into a single one with a single check. It is erroneous that people think they need several regexes to check the same string.

Answer (score 0):

While this may not be the most elegant solution, you can use the `applyFunc` parameter to pass a function that will convert blank string inputs to something that will evaluate as incorrect.

```
import re

def convert_blank(text):
    return re.sub('^\s*$', '!', s)
```

This will convert blank strings or strings consisting only of space to `'!'` using the builtin `re` module.  This of course can be adjusted to anything that is guaranteed to evaluate as incorrect.

This can then be applied to the `pyinputplus.inputStr` function call as an additional keyword argument:

```
pyinputplus.inputStr(
    task, 
    allowRegexes=['^%s$' % (num1 * num2)], 
    blockRegexes = [('.*', 'Incorrect')],
    timeout = 5, 
    limit =1,
    applyFunc=convert_blank,
    )
```